# import ES6 module with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, es6-modules, es6-class

I am trying to import an ES6 module with CoffeeScript.

The javascript working code is the following :

```
import { MyModule } from 'my-module';

const mymod = new MyModule({
  some-options: '...'
});
```

I have tried a solution documented on this [issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/3162#issuecomment-211484069) :

```
{ MyModule } = require 'my-module'
mymod = new MyModule({
  some-options: '...'
})
```

but this return the following error :

```
TypeError: MyModule is not a constructor
```

When following the documentation about it [here](https://coffeescript.org/#modules) with this code (which is really close to the original) :

```
import { MyModule } from 'my-module';

mymod = new MyModule({
  some-options: '...'
});
```

I also get an error :

```
import {
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    ...
```

How to properly import this module ? (`coffee 2.3.1` and `node v10.4.0`)

Comment: What kind of module is it? Native? It won't work then.

Comment: @estus here is the git repository about : https://github.com/Bomper/bitmex-plus

Comment: It's native module (mjs), so it cannot be imported with require. I don't do Coffee, but in order for it to work, it should be `import { MyModule } from 'my-module'` in output, too.

Comment: How / where are you running this code? Coffeescript compiles the `import` to ES6 `import` statements, so you have to ensure your environment supports it. You may want to look at `babel` and `babel-node`.

Comment: @Caffeinated.tech Yes I found out that CoffeeScript is transpilling to the right code  and that is nodejs generating the error. I'm also using some `require` in my code and it seems that I can't use both, thus totally coding in `es6` (`import`) or `es5` (`require`) but can't mix both ...

Answer (score -1):

My Meteor JS project required some customization in the Restivus package, which is originally written in CoffeeScript. To achieve this, I needed to import the 'jsonwebtoken' package. Fortunately, the below import statement worked perfectly for me.

```
jwt = Npm.require('jsonwebtoken')
```